# How do I compute the sum of an alternating series from right to left using a C program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compute the following summation from **right to left** (and compare it to the summation calculated from left to right):

1 - 1/2 + 1/3 -1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 + ... + 1/9999 - 1/10000

```
float result = 0.0;
int i = 10000;
bool flag = true;
for (int i=10000; i<1; i--) {
    if (flag == false) {
        result = result + 1.0/i;
        flag = true;
    }
    else {
        result = result - 1.0/i;
        flag = false;
    }
 }
printf("Addition from right to left accumulated in float: %f\n", result);
```

However, when I execute it, I'm getting 0.000000 as a result instead of ~0.693. I've calculated the other summation from left to right using the following code, and I'm getting my desired result.

```
bool flag = false;
float result = 0;
for (float i=1; i<=10000; i++) {
    if(flag == true) {
        result = result - 1/i;
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        result = result + 1/i;
        flag = true;
    }
}
printf("Addition from left to right accumulated in float: %f\n", result);
```

Comment: `i<1` should be `i >= 1`. `i < 1` will never be true since the initial value is `10000`.

Comment: Unrelated: strongly prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Comment: With `float` the test results differ at the 6th decimal place, with `double` at the 14th decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

In the right-to-left you should change condition to i≥1 because you want loop execution from 1000 to 1.

`for (int i=10000; i>=1; i--) {`

The output is 0 because the loop are never executed as `i` is not less than 1.

As commented double variable type is preferred.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!